# SmartWatch h/w schematic

Tags: sony-smartwatch

Is it possible to get a schematic in addition to the H/W description at http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/open-smartwatch-project/smartwatch-hacker-guide/?

Comment: I will check if we can get that for you.

Comment: Great, thank you! I have experience working with STM32F2xx as well as STEricsson FM/BT-chips but having a complete view of the hardware would speed things along.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware; try electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

Sorry we will not be able to share schematics. Could you please be a bit more specific in regards to your question, and we will see what we can do. For your reference we are working with Arduino to get a toolchain in place and I believe that you can benefit from their efforts and their work to get the toolchain in place. Please also check our [hacker guide](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/open-smartwatch-project/smartwatch-hacker-guide/) as we updated the page with links where to find the tech specs. We will also try to add more information when/if possible.

**Update**

The results from the "Proof of concept - Sony SmartWatch" workshop has now been published on GitHub. It is a complete tool chain, with support for the Arduino IDE. Check it out [here](http://github.com/underverk/SmartWatch) and [here](http://github.com/underverk/SmartWatch_Toolchain) (for command line lovers).

And also keep an eye open for more updates on the [Open Smartwatch project](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/open-smartwatch-project/) web site.

Happy hacking!

Comment: Alright, thank you for checking it out anyway. Regarding toolchain I'm using a licensed rkit-arm for ride7 for other stm development so I'm all set there. It would be helpful to know what gpio pins you've used for spi1 and spi3 and what i2c-peripheral and pins as well since different sets of gpio pins can be assigned to the respective peripherals.

Comment: Oh and also, with regards to the stlc2690 being a combined FM/Bluetooth-chip, is there any kind of antenna in the design connected to the fm core? (Even though I realize the size constraints would make it hard to have an efficient one in the unit).

Comment: This thread probably could be merged with this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117433/sony-smartwatch-open-smartwatch-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Try to find JTAG test point on PCB it's this is the best that we can use because information from Sony not full. For get full information about remapping GPIO, GPIO alternative configuration, other peripheral configuration use JTAG for dump configuration register where running original firmware. Use watchpoint for understand that and when write/read to/from peripheral register.

Comment: Do you know a way to tear down the watch without damaging it?