# Sony Smartwatch - open smartwatch getting started?

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Today almost by accident I stumbled accross the announcement that Sony is opening the firmware development and creates a project under their own hood here:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/open-smartwatch-project/

Which is great!

But it still has a lot of question marks attached:

- It would be great if there would be an open source sample firmware from which to start.
- There are some hardware parts of the device which are undocumented, especially e.g. the pretty important Bluetooth chipset ST-Ericsson STLC2690. How is one supposed to write Bluetooth software for an undocumented chip?
- There are another surely half dozen missing pieces of information, like e.g. battery charge management, battery state control, display characteristics, touchscreen characteristics etc.

The project is so extraordinarily cool and I really *want* to do something but the information is still a little too shallow.

What I would love to do is to port my "Oswald" SmartWatch project to the Sony Smartwatch:

http://labs.kernelconcepts.de/Projects/Oswald/

Oswald is currently running on MetaWatch only, for which I wrote all necessary bits&pieces, also a small Bluetooth stack. I would love to adapt this for the Smartwatch too, given some more information is revealed from Sony.

Thanks!

Cheers

nils

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking forward to opening up the possibility of custom code running on the smartwatch.

1. As soon as I get a description (or at least code to find out through..) how've they've mapped the gpio pins per peripheral I should be able to get basic code using all the as of now specified interfaces working in a few days.
2. I've based code on https://code.google.com/p/btstack/ and modified it a bit to get it working with a STEricsson CG2900 and stm32f205 so hopefully we'll get BT up and working in not too much time. If it's just the Bluetooth part you're interested in the interface on HCI level is pretty much standardized.
3. Agree, as you might've noticed I asked for a hardware schematic but we won't be getting one.

Comment: I could mention that've worked with s STEricssson CG2900 so hopefully blueooth will be up soon.

Comment: Mapping the diferrent peripherals to the different gpio:s is currently an option. Let's coordinate and share what we find out. I have too worked on a design with a STM32F205 interfacing a CG2900. I'm sure they'res some code we can share. I'm also using BTStack.

Comment: I could also add that I have access to the STLC2690 documentation through my work. Obviously I can't share it but I suppose it's fine that I produce code to get the chip going and publish that.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more depth to the Open SmartWatch project - the results from the "Proof of concept - Sony SmartWatch" workshop has now been published on GitHub. It is a complete tool chain, with support for the Arduino IDE. Check it out [here](http://github.com/underverk/SmartWatch) and [here](http://github.com/underverk/SmartWatch_Toolchain) (for command line lovers).

I think you will find a lot of answers to your questions. Please feel free to contribute!

And also keep an eye open for more updates on the [Open Smartwatch project](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/open-smartwatch-project/) web site.

Comment: I've been looking for any example bluetooth code in the Open SmartWatch project, but couldn't find any, has anybody gotten that part working?