# Does Sony Smartwatch USB connector support OTG?

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm searching for any way to get a hardware signal into the Sony Smartwatch.

I see from this question in another place:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/why-does-micro-usb-2-0-have-5-pins-when-the-a-type-only-has-4/35468#35468
that USB connectors can have an extra input which normally floats but can be grounded, the On-The-Go signal.

I see the Smartwatch schematics are not being released:
[SmartWatch h/w schematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088504/smartwatch-h-w-schematic)

So, **does the USB connector on the Smartwatch support the On-The-Go input**? If so, **is there any way to find the status of that input in a Smartwatch Android app**?

Answer (score 1):

> The SmartWatch only supports USB 2.0, i.e. it acts as a device, not
>   host.

MCU use same GPIO pins for USB controller (if this model MCU realy have USB OTG). No limitation except you can't detect that is connected USB OTG cable and can't power pluged USB device (need external power).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select usb mode only in you firmware without detect what cable plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The SmartWatch only supports USB 2.0, i.e. it acts as a device, not host. Additionally, the SmartExtension SDK exposes no API for this kind of device specific information.

However, keep an eye open for updates on our [Open SmartWatch project](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/open-smartwatch-project/) site - there might be possibilities for you to create your own USB implementation.

**Update**

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088504/smartwatch-h-w-schematic) - tool chain and Arduino IDE published for hacking SmartWatch.

Comment: Thanks! @Exception13 here makes a good point - the MCU provides a USB interface that can be reconfigured as a GPIO interface if I get very enthusiastic with changes to the firmware. Does the hardware connect the DM pin of the USB connector direct to the OTG_FS_DM pin of the MCU, which is GPIO pin PA11? and DP to PA12? So the device uses the "full speed" USB hardware described in the MCU data sheet at section 2.2.28?